# Assign a reference to a `Function` using Reflection

Tags: java

With Java 8 it's now possible to get a reference to a method as a first class object using the `::` syntax like this:

```
Map<Integer, String> strings = new HashMap<>();
...

Function<Integer, String> get = strings::get;
...
```

How do I achieve the same assignment using reflection (as opposed to coding it as shown)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using (raw code warning):

```
Map<Integer, String> strings = new HashMap<>();
...

Method getMethod = strings.getClass().getMethod("get", Object.class);
Function<Integer, String> function = i -> getMethod.invoke(strings, i);
```

Your job now is to ensure that the parameter to `get` is an integer, and that it returns a specific type and to handle the exceptions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection will give you a method such as

```
Method get = Map.class.getMethod("get", Object.class);
```

however this doesn't bind to an object like you have in your example.  What you can do is use [MethodHandles.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html)  This can be bound to an object but I don't remember the exact syntax.

Comment: Poking about in `MethodHandles` as we type, just can't quite follow through to the point I get a `Function`